# Safe to use bigger heater element?

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station, hot-air, rework

So here's the run down, I purchased a rework/soldering iron station off eBay years ago. Believe it's a cheap Chinese knock off labeled CE 852D+

Recently the heater element for soldering iron went bad. Bought what I thought would be an exact replacement but it was slightly longer. Original on top

[image]

Tried installing and this was the result

[image]

I tested it and it seems to work fine in terms of heating up and detecting the temp setting. I'm wondering if I alter the little indents on the bottom that seat into the soldering iron PCB so it recesses just enough to fit flush, if it would be safe to use?

I also noticed writing on the iron handle that faded and all I can make out is "907" and the last letter I think was an "A"

Also the soldering iron PCB has a "YH936B-5" marking on it[image]

Should I be looking for a heater element for a 907A instead of the station 852D+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the old element is already bad, I would recess it twice so much to see, if I would hit comething other, than just ceramic cover. If in the double depth is not anything else than ceramic, I would feel confident to recess the new one the single lenght. (But the less it is recessed, the better)

(douyble the recess, so I would be sure, that I did not stopped "just a hair" from heating wire, and that the new one have probably enought of isolation left after shorting it)

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying to recess the tip? I was thinking lengthening the two notches on the bottom so it sits lower on the PCB of soldering iron

Comment: So I did not understood you question well, my bad. (English is not my native lang). IMHO if you lenghten the nothes, it is safer way, as it can be undone. But the wide part might serve as support too, so make sure, it still fits well mechanically. I think, it will be OK too. On my soldering station I would do it and I think it would work OK, but it have slightly different construction.

Comment: It wouldn't cause any damage to the station if say the heater element resistances internally aren't identical?

Comment: Ops, I did not think about that, as you did not mentioned it and I would order something with same electrical characteristics if I could. So if the resistance is nearly the same, it is not problem, as it gets regulated depending on the temperature generated. But if your new heater have lesser resistance, it would enable more current thru and may damage the station (I would not risk take more than 10% more current, if I do not know the characteristic)

Comment: on the other hand if the new have larger resistance, the current will be much less and so the power, so it would not be able to reach maximum temperature consistently (if at all) and will take longer to heat-up, but it probably would not harm the station (see if there is something in documentation - mainly if it say that turning the station on without heating pen attach can harm it, then big resistance can have similar effect, but I do not expect current-source there. Voltage source with PWM or swithing on/off is IMHO more usual)

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/907A-Solder-Soldering-Rework-Station-Iron-for-W-E-P-936-936C-853DA-898D-8786D-/261673958132

Comment: This is exact listing I purchased the heater elements from. Says it's for 852D+ but they were bigger than original https://www.ebay.com/itm/161568266487

Comment: here https://www.amazon.com/Zeny-Soldering-Rework-Station-852D/dp/B00NINOV56  it says in comments that the 852D+ use 24V and 70W, while here http://www.ebay.com/itm/907A-Solder-Soldering-Rework-Station-Iron-for-W-E-P-936-936C-853DA-898D-8786D-/261673958132 it says, that it use 24V 50W only. So the voltage is the same and it would be safe to use heater from 907A in 852D+ station (but it will be slow heating), (but not use heater from 852D+ in 907A station). If you get already the right temperature, it should be all OK.

Comment: Weird because I remember when I got the 852D+ that it was 24v 50w

Comment: this comment says 70/80W https://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx3GX73F2Z75PN2/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B00NINOV56 and that with 50W it would be low performance. This discussion http://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/w-e-p-yihua-852d-combined-hot-air-station-and-soldering-iron/ says, how is china approach to the case. Anyway 50W 24V heater should be OK. (the worst case is it would just heat-up slower, than what you had before)

Comment: Thanks I also noticed the soldering iron PCB has a "YH936B-5" marking on it. Updated post with a picture of it

Comment: I went ahead and used the replacement heater. What I noticed is solder is melting at a lower temperature than it was with the old heater. I can melt leaded solder with a beveled tip at 155c where with the old heater it would have to be set to around 230c. What do you think?

Comment: Lower resistance, more Wats, than the previous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder states 183 °C as melting point of clasical sorder, so the 155C is probably a lie (wrong kind of sensor) 230 sounds more trusty. Anyway if you just accept the false values and set it according your needs for soldering (not for temperature on display) and keep that value, it should be OK, as it takes the same amount of energy to heat to the same actual temp. Just go with 155C (or little more) and be happy :) Until you reach real max temp, nothing should be wrong. The station should not be much warmer than usual.

Comment: Cool. Just interesting because the old measures 12.5 ohms for the sensor and 2.0 for heater. Replacement is 14.5 for the sensor and .9 for heater